# Laravel href with POST

Tags: laravel, parameter-passing, action

I'm trying to pass some data to my controller with an action `href`. I don't know why, but laravel passes the data with ***GET*** method, but instead of ***GET*** I need a ***POST***. I don't really understand why laravel does that and coulnd't find an answer. I did that multiple times and my syntax seems to be correct. Can somebody have a look over it?

**Blade:**

```
 <td>
 @foreach($products as $product)
        <a href="{{ action('ProductsController@delete', $product->id ) }}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a> 
               {{ $product->name }},
 @endforeach
 </td>
```

**My Route:**

```
Route::post('delete', ['as' => 'delete', 'uses' => 'ProductController@delete']);
```

In my Controller is just a:

```
public function delete()
{
    return 'hello'; // just testing if it works
}
```

**Error:**

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219....
```

I know it's a get method, cause if I'm trying to pass the data to my controller, my URL looks like this:

```
blabla.../products/delete?10
```

Is anything wrong with my syntax? I can't really see why it uses the get method. 
I also tried a: `data-method="post"` insite of my `<a>` tag but this haven't worked either.

Thanks for taking time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you make a link with an anchor like `<a href=example.com>` your method will always be GET. This is like opening a URL in your browser, you make a GET request.

You should use a form to make that POST request to the delete method of the controller. Assuming you have the Illuminate HTML package for HTML and forms, you could do this:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => $route]) !!}
{!! Form::submit('delete', ['onclick' => 'return confirm("Are you sure?");']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**EDIT:**
With a button tag:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => $route]) !!}
<button type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Delete</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: okay, this works. But how I can do this with this glyphicon-trash class? I don't want a submit button over there

Comment: @WellNo you could use a button tag instead of submit.

Comment: I stried it with a button tag, but this haven't worked well. Maybe it's my syntax. Could you do me example?

Comment: I also tried it this way, but I don't want this submit box around the icon :/ just the icon itself, is there any way to do this? if not I will do some changes with css :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's your problem:

```
<a href="{{ action('ProductsController@delete', $product->id ) }}">
```

Anchor tags are always submitted over GET. It's a HTTP built in and is not Laravel specific.

POST is used when a form is submitted that specifies the POST HTTP Verb or the HTTP method is invoked by an AJAX request that specifies POST as the HTTP Verb.

Instead consider a `submit` type button in a form that submits what you need.

```
    <td>
        @foreach($products as $product)
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('delete') }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ $product->id }}">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <button type="submit" class="btn">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </button>
            </form>
            {{ $product->name }},
        @endforeach
    </td>
```

And then in your controller:

```
    public function delete()
    {
        // 'Die Dump' all of the input from the form / request
        dd( request()->input()->all() );

        // 'Die Dump' the specific input from the form
        dd( request()->input('product_id') );
    }
```

You will begin to see how GET and POST requests differ in sending of key/value pairs.

For more information:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm

Answer (score 3):

> Best for laravel 7. First define the form with given form id.

```
@auth
   <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" 
     style="display: none;">
       @csrf
  </form>
 @endauth
```

Then you can use the anchor tag for logout operation.In background,javascript  working.Wherever the logout was fire then action to given form method of post method and logout route  was working.

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-muted waves-effect waves-dark"
                              href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"
id="2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> 
                                  <i class="mdi mdi-logout"></i>
</a>
```

> Most benefit is the form was not loaded unnecesory.If the user was
>   logged in so far its load otherwise not

Answer (score 3):

****Laravel 7****

By `jQuery`:

```
<form id="form" action="{{route('route_name')}}" method="POST">@csrf</form>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#form').submit()"></a>
```

By `JS`:

```
<form id="form" action="{{route('route_name')}}" method="POST">@csrf</form>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit()"></a>
```